# How to get rid of port from url

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I'm getting frustrated how to run my wordpress dev environment without port in URL. At best I would like to use virtual host like "mysite.com".

I am on Ubuntu and using Docker to run wordpress locally.

1. I have added line into file /etc/hosts
   `127.0.0.1  mysite.com`
2. I stopped apache2 to free port 80 `sudo service apache2 stop`
3. Then I set up my docker-compose.yaml file to expose wordpress to port 80 and run in.

Unfortunately when I try to go on localhost or mysite.com I'm immediately redirected to localhost:8000 and browser shows me that page is not found.

Ok, backward verification `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :80` and yes! Wordpress running in docker is using port 80. So what is going on? What else should I do? I need at least get rid of port from URL.

Comment: Are there some config in wordpress where port can be set? Or .htaccess file what do redirect? I have no experience with wordpress, but good at apache configs and virtualhosts.

Comment: Have you system apache, not docker, what can intercept a request?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to configure docker apache to use 8080 port, and configure system apache to proxy request on some particular virtual host to proxy requests to docker 8080

In frontend apache virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Config is located at `/ect/apache/sites-availabe/` and enabled by `a2ensite configname`

Comment: I'm using following image https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/ which already contains an apache and it works fine inside docker. There is only need to set up to what port I want to expose it to my system. There si no problem when I configure the image's port for example on 8081 but then there is also port in my URL. Therefore I strive to run it on port 80 but it seems there must be something wrong in Ubuntu because I got the redirecting every time I try to go on the address. I will try to configure system apache as you advise just please give me file path. I'm not sure to which one to edit.

Comment: I guess wrong thing is: ports below 1024 need root, so you have to use 8080 in docker. I have added path to config to answer. You need to edit both, docker and system apache

Comment: Port 8080 uses phpmyadmin  so I set port for wordpress image to 8081. I also edited the file accordingly. However I am not sure what was supposed to happen. Wordpress site runs now on address localhost:8081 but still I got the port in URL

Comment: Try https://mysite.com:80, system apache must handle it, and proxy to docker. May be there are default virtualhost intercepting request. default virtualhost should be disabled or edited. try `a2dissite 000-defalut.conf` or edit this file to the config in the answer. Im going to sleep, see you next day.